# Cropper - Crop image in polygon

Tags: javascript, cropper

Is it possible, to crop an image in the form of a polygon? Using Cropper (A simple jQuery image cropping plugin) at fengyuanchen [in Github](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)

### Expected behavior

I have a image to crop with Cropper, and I want to crop into 6 sides. Hexagon. 
See attached.

Hexagon image:
[image: Hexagon image]

Well, I know it's possible to crop rounded, is soft. But for five or six sides is hard.
anybody some idea, for work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any knowledge regarding this but A hexagon can be made by rotating a rectangle at an axis 2 times at 60 degrees. Crop the rectangle with your dimensions and then rotate your rectangle at 60 degrees and crop again and then rotate your rectangle at 60 degrees and crop again.

Comment: yes, thanks. I trying used CSS like crop image round. but not work.